# installing gnuplot software on windows

Tags: installation, gnuplot

I downloaded the gnuplot (5.0) software from https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.0.5/
 can anyone help me in installing the program on my PC (Windows7-32 bit)? 
Thank You.

Comment: No need to install it, download the 5.0.4 zip file, extract it and execute `bin\wgnuplot.exe`.

Comment: @Christoph yes, it works ..Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There is (as of today) not a binary for version 5.0.5.

You can grab the 5.0.4 from here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.0.4/

If you really need the 5.0.5, you can recompile it from scratch (but you need to satisfy a lot of dependencies)

Comment: i downloaded the file.exe, i tried to run it, it gives me an error mesage says: The setup files are corrupted. Please obtain a new copy of the program. what shall i do now? @bibi

Comment: with the 32 bit version? https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.0.4/gp504-win32-mingw.exe/download

Comment: yes, it's 32bit, it keeps giving me the message again,

Comment: Strange because it works well on my win machine. No idea why it's failing on your machine could you try to go back with revisions? https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.0.3/

Comment: can you please provide me with the setup downloaded on your PC ? using dropbox maybe! @bibi

Comment: all I did was to download the `.exe` file, double-click on it and follow the installation process. Once done I had an applicaiton in the taskbar: gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 4 and cicked on it